# SignalR issues with existing website

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

When I am trying to add SignalR in our existing web application (with MVC 4) I am getting below error message on page load.

Message: Unable to get value of the property 'signalR': object is null or undefined
URI: http://dev.casino.bwin.com/signalr/hubs

I tried to navigate to signalr/hubs jquery and it seems to be working fine as my client hub class is available in the javascript.

Any pointers on what i might be doing wrong.

Comment: One common cause of this issue is including jQuery twice on the page. In MVC projects usually there's jQuery included in the layout page and people often forget that.

Answer (score 0):

You should be including "Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.0.1.min.js" after jQuery but before the "/signalr/hubs" script.

Look at Javascript + HTML Client section of  http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client for reference.